# Ruby passing partial args to function with defaults

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm new to Capybara, rspec & Ruby, I have a function to fill a form:

```
def form_fill(name:'James', age:'25', pets:'cat')
    fill_in 'Name', with: name
    fill_in 'Age' , with: age
    fill_in 'Pets', with: pets
end
```

And I was wondering what to change in the function so I could modify the form (which I filled already), using the same function again.

for example:
I did `form_fill(name:'Bob')`, and now my form is:

```
Name   Age    Pets
----   ----   ----
Bob    25     cats
```

Later I want to change the same saved form, and only to change the age by invoking the same function with just the argument of age: form_fill(age:45).

Which at this time will change the form using the defaults into:

```
Name   Age    Pets
----   ----   ----
James  45     cats
```

So I was wondering how to achieve the same funcion as a filler & a modifier at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just need to use a Plain Old Ruby Object class here. First I would create a Person class that you will use for setting attributes about a person.

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :age, :pets

  def initialize(name: "James", age: 45, pets: "cat")
    @name = name
    @age = age
    @pets = pets
  end
end
```

This will allow you to do the following:

```
person = Person.new(name: "Bob")
=> #<Person:0x007fac4bb27128 @age=45, @name="Bob", @pets="cat">
```

Then in the Capybara method do this:

```
def form_fill(person)
  fill_in 'Name', with: person.name
  fill_in 'Age' , with: person.age
  fill_in 'Pets', with: person.pets
end
```

When you would like to modify the person:

```
person.age = 25
form_fill(person)
```

Hope this helps!